# HTML unusual spacing between elements

Tags: html, css

I have the following menu.

[image: topmenu]

HTML code

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="links">
            <span class="link" href="#">Toate</span>
            <span class="link" href="#">Online</span>
            <span class="link" href="#">Noi</span>
            <span class="link" href="#">Top</span>
        </div>
        <div class="profile"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS Code

```
.topmenu {
    background: #6b00f3 linear-gradient(180deg, #7f0000, #6b0103) repeat scroll 0 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 48px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 }
.topmenu .container {
    height: 100%;
}
.topmenu .container .links {
    height: 100%;
}
.topmenu .container .links .link {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #fff;
}
.topmenu .container .links .link:not(:last-child) {
    border: 1px solid #630000;
}
```

Now, there is a spacing between my .link elements. There is no margin, no padding. 
If I copy-paste the div.links into body, the same result (with no CSS applied). If I copy only the span.link elements in the body, there is no spacing between them.
I tried adding width: auto on .links. I tried switching between  and  and  for the .link. Tried display: inline, inline-flex, inline-block... Nothing worked!

How do I fix this ?

Comment: You have this rule padding: 0 10px;

Comment: Your example is entirely missing the .topmenu class, so none of your CSS will apply... is this maybe also the problem for your live page?

Comment: i've added the .topmenu rules. missed them by mistake... @spekdrum that padding is for inside the link.. the borders show where the element is ending

Comment: I'm guessing this is the normal *spacing* of inline elements, resulting from the whitespace in your html code. If so, there's a ton of ways to get rid of it, all with their own problems. E.g. remove the whitepsace, `float: left`...

Comment: In addition of @spekdrum that you have a padding, inline elements (like `<span>`) will be attached in the text line, so all spaces will be rendered, and yes, your line breaking and tabs are spaces too.

Comment: even if i add padding: 0 the result is the same. is spacing between elements   it has nothing to do with the inside of them

Comment: No this is not inline block. this is as explained spaces between the span elements, since span is inline, spaces will apear if there are any in the html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`span` is an inline element. Put them on the same line with no space between them like this:

`<span class="link" href="#">Toate</span><span class="link" href="#">Online</span><span class="link" href="#">Noi</span><span class="link" href="#">Top</span>`

That should remove the spacing between them.

Comment: this worked. waiting 6 minutes to pass to mark this answer

Comment: IF they're links, you should change them to `<a>` tags. Or an inline-list with `<a>` tags

Comment: More info on html blocks: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

Comment: The REASON for this is inline elements are treated like words of text and words of text have their own whitespace between them. This is why the whitespace is generated.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because each span is on its own line, as HappyDane and rkrishnan suggests, and HTML interprets newlines as a space. If you want to keep each span on its own line, you can set `font-size` of the parent element to `0`, and `font-size` of .link to `1rem` (or whatever).

Comment: No, this is not the reason. The reason is because inline elements are treated like words on a page and words are separated by whitespace. Lines have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

A little confused here about what you are after. I think your after removing the padding between the elements. Where you have added them with 'padding: 0 10px;' the second figure is left and right padding the first being vertical.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the markup you can set `font-size:0;` to the parent element (in this case `.links`) and then set the font-size for the `span` accordingly. This will also remove the spacing

Answer (score 0):

Use "float:left" for the '.link' span to remove the unnecessary space in between them.

```
.topmenu .container .links .link {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This what you are looking for? I could not really understand your question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   .container, .link {
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 1px;
     background-color: red;
     float: left;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="links">
        <span class="link" href="#">Toate</span>
        <span class="link" href="#">Online</span>
        <span class="link" href="#">Noi</span>
        <span class="link" href="#">Top</span>
    </div>
    <div class="profile"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hLdufx77/)**

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="links">
    <span class="link" href="#">Toate</span><span class="link" href="#">Online</span><span class="link" href="#">Noi</span><span class="link" href="#">Top</span>
  </div>
  <div class="profile"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.topmenu {
    background: #6b00f3 linear-gradient(180deg, #7f0000, #6b0103) repeat scroll 0 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 48px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 }
.topmenu .container {
    height: 100%;
}
.topmenu .container .links {
    height: 100%;
}
.topmenu .container .links .link {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #fff;
}
.topmenu .container .links .link:not(:last-child) {
    border: 1px solid #630000;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add **float:left** in your CSS for .link class as following. This will float your elements to left inside parent DIV. Hence will remove spacing.

```
.topmenu .container .links .link {
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 100%;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 0 10px;
color: #fff;
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

A possible quick fix for this would be to remove the spacing in the HTML code. 
It's a common known bug, that browsers renders it wrong.

Your HTML code would have to look like this:

```
 <span class="link" href="#">Toate</span><span class="link" href="#">Online</span><span class="link" href="#">Noi</span><span class="link" href="#">Top</span>
```

There can't be any spacing between the SPAN classes.

Comment: NO!!! It's not a bug. A bug should be the opposite.

Comment: Are you really saying that if the HTML is `<span>hello</span> <span>world</span>`, the browser should render it as "helloworld"?